# Rdio.com interface - reorganising number of albums in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, user-interface, responsive-design

I've been really impressed with the http://www.rdio.com UI. (log in first)

I would like to know how they reorganise the number of album covers in the central div being populated in rows, determined by screen size. (Have a go at scaling it up and down).

I realise they're using a responsive stylesheet, but what determines the population of the number of albums in each row? Is this javascript of some sort? or is it actually being done by the responsive CSS stylesheet?

Are there any jQuery scripts / plugins out there which do a similar thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done with JavaScript, but I don't know any specific jQuery plugins for that exact behaviour, except maybe for [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com) (note quite sure if it can do this).

However i can explain and show you the basics for such a *tile view*. You need a prefered size for your items. On resize you calculate how many items would fit into the container, then ceil that value, this will give you either the exact number of items that fits at the prefered size, or the next higher number of items to fit in the container

```
itemsPerRow = ceil(containerWidth / preferedSize)
```

Now that you have the number of items that fits or must be fit, calculate the possibly scaled size which you can then apply to the items

```
scaledSize = containerWidth / itemsPerRow
```

You also need to decide how to position the items... you could float them:

http://jsfiddle.net/Uuaht/

but that might be a bit flaky and stuff, positioning them absolutely looks better:

http://jsfiddle.net/3wLZC/

As I said, this is just the basics, but it should get you started.

### Code for the jsfiddle examples:

#### Floating

*HTML*

```
<div id='grid'>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
</div>
```

*JS*

```
var grid = $('#grid');
var items = $('.item');

var preferedSize = 200;

function resize()
{
    var gridWidth = grid.width();
    var perRow = Math.ceil(gridWidth / preferedSize);
    var size = gridWidth / perRow;

    items.css({
        width: size + 'px',
        height: size + 'px'
    });
}

$(window).on('resize', resize);
resize();
```

*CSS*

```
.item {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/nasa.jpg');
    background-size: contain;
}
```

#### Absolute positioning

*JS*

```
var grid = $('#grid');
var items = $('.item');

var preferedSize = 200;

function resize()
{
    var gridWidth = grid.width();
    var perRow = Math.ceil(gridWidth / preferedSize);
    var size = gridWidth / perRow;

    var row = 0;
    var col = 0;

    items.each(function(index, element)
    {
        var item = $(element);
        item.css({
            top: (row * size) + 'px',
            left: (col * size) + 'px',
            width: size + 'px',
            height: size + 'px'
        });

        col ++;
        if(index % perRow == perRow - 1)
        {
            row ++
            col = 0;
        }
    });
}

$(window).on('resize', resize);
resize();
```

*CSS*

```
.item {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/nasa.jpg');
    background-size: contain;
}
```